# strtok - предположительно выдает не верный результат

Tags: c

Не совсем могу правильно понять результат работы `strtok`:

Я взял полностью пример с [strtok](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

и просто заменил строку и подстроку на свои:

```
int main() 
{

    char str[] = "hih1ihi";
    char* pch;
    printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n", str);
    pch = strtok(str, "hi");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, "hi");
    }

}
```

Из строки "**hi**h1i**hi**" и подстроки "hi" и применении `strtok` - я ожидал увидеть следующий результат:

> h1i

Так как разделитель hi - теоретически должен был бы быть отброшен, но `strtok` выдает только:

> 1

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtok` работает не так. Вторым аргументом она принимает строку разделителей, а не строку-разделитель. Т.е. каждый символ из этой строки является разделителем, что Вы и наблюдаете. В Вашем случае разделителями выступают символы `h` и `i`, а не целая строка `hi`. Т.к. в строке `hih1ihi` кроме разделителей есть только символ `1`, то его программа и выводит.